TypeScript with RTK and builder cases
I followed this link for usage of TypeScript with redux toolkit but still couldn't figure out the issue when it comes to data type.
interface IDashboard {
    findGoals: { status: string; data: Goal[]; error: string | null; };
    findSchedule: { status: string; data: []; error: string | null; };
}

const initialState: IDashboard = {
    findGoals: { data: [], status: ApplicationConstants.IDLE, error: null },
    findSchedule: { data: [], status: ApplicationConstants.IDLE, error: null },
};

const dashboard = createSlice({
    name: "dashboard",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(findGoals.pending, state => {
                state.findGoals = {data: [], status: ApplicationConstants.LOADING, error: null};
            })
            .addCase(findGoals.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<Goal[]>) => {
                state.findGoals = {data: action.payload, status: ApplicationConstants.SUCCEEDED, error: null};
            })
            .addCase(findGoals.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.findGoals = {data: [], status: ApplicationConstants.FAILED, error: action.error};
            });

        builder
            .addCase(findSchedule.pending, state => {
                state.findSchedule = {data: [], status: ApplicationConstants.LOADING, error: null};
            })
            .addCase(findSchedule.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.findSchedule = {data: action.payload, status: ApplicationConstants.SUCCEEDED, error: null};
            })
            .addCase(findSchedule.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.findSchedule = {data: [], status: ApplicationConstants.FAILED, error: action.error};
            });
    }
});

ApplicationConstants
export class ApplicationConstants {
    static IDLE = "idle";
    static LOADING = "loading";
    static SUCCEEDED = "succeeded";
    static FAILED = "failed";
}

methods
export const findGoals = createAsyncThunk("dashboard/findGoals",

    async (client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const GET_GOALS = gql`
                query Goals {
                    goals {
                        id
                        title
                        description
                        percentage
                    }
                }
            `;

            client.query({ query: GET_GOALS })
                .then(response => resolve(response.data.goals))
                .catch(error => reject(error));
        });
    }
);

Goal
export interface Goal {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    percentage: string;
}

Store
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        dashboard: dashboard,
    }
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;


Attempt
I used the type for action as action: PayloadAction<Goal[]> without any success for the first addCase.
Question:
Please advise on what type signature to use with the action for both fulfilled (action.payload) and rejected (action.error) cases.
Screenshot: See the red lines.


Edit
If I hover over data I see the following TypeScript warning
TS2740: Type RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> is missing the following properties from type WritableDraft<Goal>[]: length, pop, push, concat, and 35 more.
dashboard. ts(7, 34): The expected type comes from property data which is declared here on type


and If I hover over error I see the following TypeScript warnings
TS2322: Type SerializedError is not assignable to type string
dashboard. ts(7, 48): The expected type comes from property error which is declared here on type



What is the actual issue here and can you also [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

@DrewReese please see the edit section at the bottom, I'm confused and need help with what type to use to make the warnings go away.

Can you also add a complete [mcve], e.g. the asynchronous actions, the complete state slice file, the configureStore, and any other code parts you think might be relevant?

Yes, I just added async methods, and the store

I don't see any overt issues in what you've shared here in your post, and I'm unable to copy/paste this code and reproduce the issue you describe. See if you can create a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces the Typescript errors/warnings that we can inspect live.

wow, is it possible that it's my IDE (WebStorm), Are you on VS Code? As you can see from the screenshots, the red underlines for data and the error

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I was unable to reproduce the exact issue/error you describe here, but I think your implementation is not helping and might actually be working against you. The findGoals action logic can be simplified a bit using standard async/await instead of wrapping up the logic in an additional Promise chain.
Example:
export const findGoals = createAsyncThunk(
  "dashboard/findGoals",
  async (client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>) => {
    const GET_GOALS = gql`
      query Goals {
        goals {
          id
          title
          description
          percentage
        }
      }
    `;

    const response = await client.query({ query: GET_GOALS });
    return response.data.goals as Goal[];
  }
);

The only additional change I needed to add was to cast the action.error to string from its default SerializedError type.
const dashboard = createSlice({
  name: "dashboard",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(findGoals.pending, (state) => {
        state.findGoals = {
          data: [],
          status: ApplicationConstants.LOADING,
          error: null,
        };
      })
      .addCase(findGoals.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.findGoals = {
          data: action.payload,
          status: ApplicationConstants.SUCCEEDED,
          error: null,
        };
      })
      .addCase(findGoals.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.findGoals = {
          data: [],
          status: ApplicationConstants.FAILED,
          error: action.error as string, // <--
        };
      });

    builder
      .addCase(findSchedule.pending, (state) => {
        state.findSchedule = {
          data: [],
          status: ApplicationConstants.LOADING,
          error: null,
        };
      })
      .addCase(findSchedule.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.findSchedule = {
          data: action.payload,
          status: ApplicationConstants.SUCCEEDED,
          error: null,
        };
      })
      .addCase(findSchedule.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.findSchedule = {
          data: [],
          status: ApplicationConstants.FAILED,
          error: action.error as string, // <--
        };
      });
  },
});

Also, FWIW, RTK utilizes Immer.js under the hood, so it allows you to write mutable state updates, so there's no need to create new findGoals and findSchedule object references, RTK takes care of this for you auto-magically.
Example:
const dashboard = createSlice({
  name: "dashboard",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(findGoals.pending, (state) => {
        state.findGoals.status = ApplicationConstants.LOADING;
      })
      .addCase(findGoals.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.findGoals.data = action.payload;
        state.findGoals.states = ApplicationConstants.SUCCEEDED;
      })
      .addCase(findGoals.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.findGoals.status = ApplicationConstants.FAILED;
        state.findGoals.error = action.error as string;
      });

    builder
      .addCase(findSchedule.pending, (state) => {
        state.findSchedule.status = ApplicationConstants.LOADING;
      })
      .addCase(findSchedule.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.findSchedule.data = action.payload;
        state.findSchedule.states = ApplicationConstants.SUCCEEDED;
      })
      .addCase(findSchedule.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.findSchedule.status = ApplicationConstants.FAILED;
        state.findSchedule.error = action.error as string;
      });
  },
});


Thanks Drew. quick question, is my approach okay for the initialState where I nested data, status and error of each API call, and updated them separately. I'm new and never done this before.

@AppDeveloper It is subjective how you decide to breakdown/group/organize your state. Generally you want to group related values that are commonly updated together or are "units" of similar properties, like your API statuses. I don't see any issue with the way you've currently structured your dashboard state, but you could just as validly create a state slice for each API and combine them to create your common dashboard reducer that the store uses. I hope that made sense to you.
